# Firebase Storage: serving content to anonymous signed users without token

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to serve an image hosted on Firebase Storage only to users that are logged in  anonymously. Here is my storage rule:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider == "anonymous";
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work:

- If I go to
  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project.appspot.com/o/image.png (without the token in the url) it gives me 403
- If I go to https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project.appspot.com/o/image.png?token=tokenId it serves the image, but it serves it to anyone (logged, not logged, etc.)

Also tried with the default rule:

```
allow read: if request.auth != null;
```

Same thing. The simulator works fine but in production it just doesn't work. Am I forgetting anything here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The second URL you show seems to be a download URL, which (by definition) give read-only access to the resource to anyone who has that URL. There is no way to protect access through security rules for download URLs.

The first URL only works when access through the Firebase SDK, or when you explicitly set up the Cloud Storage security on the bucket to allow public access, which would bypass Firebase security rules completely.

Firebase [JavaScript SDK 9.5](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#9.5.0) just added methods to access the data through the SDK, so I recommend checking those out.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen - although I can't find any documentation on Storage getBlob()... only for [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot)

Comment: They're in the modular SDK as top-level functions: e.g. [`getBlob`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#getblob). It looks like they were not added to the compat mode libraries.